# State in SLS file is not formed as a list

Tags: yaml, salt-stack

I've got an sls file; the contents of which follow:

```
apache:
 pkg.installed:
    -name: apache2
 service.running:
   -enable: True
   - require:
     - pkg: apache
```

And I'm getting the error when trying to provision an Ubuntu Vagrant box with salt using the salt-master:

```
State 'apache' in SLS 'webserver' is not formed as a list
```

I've tried editing it and I've noticed that you can't have a chunk of code ending in a `:` but I can't see what's wrong with this.

The salt-master is running on an Ubuntu box and the key is accepted. I'm new to salt!

I've just put it through an on-line YAML parser and it seems to be okay. Wot is I missin'?

Answer (score 5):

I don't think you need the double space indent, mine works with single, but you do need a space after the dashes.

```
apache:
  pkg.installed:
    - name: apache2
  service.running:
    - enable: True
    - require:
      - pkg: apache
```

Answer (score 4):

Looks like the spacing is wrong. You need a double "white space" not a single. Try this.

```
apache:
  pkg.installed:
    -name: apache2
  service.running:
    -enable: True
    - require:
      - pkg: apache
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use the following: 
https://yamlvalidator.com/

Or with this one liner python:

```
python -c 'import yaml,sys;yaml.safe_load(sys.stdin)' < /srv/salt/state.sls
```

Comment: That complains about a % in my Bash. `python3 -c 'import yaml, sys; yaml.safe_load("/salt/state.jinja")' ` works.